# XAML to C# Conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="columnCategory" Width="10*">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Width="{Binding ElementName=columnCategory, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource RightMarginSetter}, ConverterParameter=20}"/>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

How can i write my above XAML expression in C#?

Comment: Have a look at the MSDN of DataGrid. This might give you a hint on how to do it. There is an example in C# at the end of this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I assume that you're talking about the `Width` element?  Why would you want to?  Binding your UI property to a c# property is how you would accomplish a variable width.  All of the backing parts of this are *already* c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example without test...

```
        ComboBox headerCombo = new ComboBox() { HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left };
        Binding myBinding = new Binding()
        {
            ElementName = "columnCategory",
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
            Converter = new RightMarginSetter(),
            ConverterParameter = 20
        };
        headerCombo.SetBinding(ComboBox.WidthProperty, myBinding);

        DataGridTextColumn columnCategory = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = headerCombo };
```